# ActiveMQ java.io.EOFException

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I am using the activeMQ 5.13.0 and my java is openjdk-1.8.0.131.
I deployed them on my linux server desktop(centos7).my producer was a ruby file to send the message which was located on my another linux server(centos6) desktop.

I do not do anyting update to my activemq.xml before I start my activemq.
The transport connector is:

```
<transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="amqp" uri="amqp://0.0.0.0:5672?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0"/>
        <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61613?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
        <transportConnector name="ws" uri="ws://0.0.0.0:61614?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

For I am using virtual topic, I add some virtual topic setting as below:

```
<destinationInterceptors>
        <virtualDestinationInterceptor>
            <virtualDestinations>
            <!-- deliver traffic from virtual topic T to all subscribers to destinations matching the prefix "VirtualQueueConsumer.*" (queue or topic) -->
                <virtualTopic name="VirtualTopic.eng.testing" prefix="VirtualQueueConsumer.*." />
            </virtualDestinations>
        </virtualDestinationInterceptor>
</destinationInterceptors>
```

For my producer, I sent my topic to my broker "      amqp://10.66.136.171:5672"

when I am using the producer to send the message to the active broker. from the activemq log, I get the following error. But on my broker webconsole, I can get the my topic has been shown on the page. The error happens when I send my message. I have no idea which steps of acticemq raise the exception.
Here are the errors reproted by activemq console and the log of my producers.

error log:

```
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://10.73.60.105:58722 failed:
java.io.EOFException
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.DataInputStream.readFully(DataInputStream.java:197)
at org.fusesource.hawtbuf.Buffer.readFrom(Buffer.java:412)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.amqp.AmqpWireFormat.unmarshal(AmqpWireFormat.java:102)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.readCommand(TcpTransport.java:240)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.doRun(TcpTransport.java:232)
at org.apache.activemq.transport.tcp.TcpTransport.run(TcpTransport.java:215)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If the message is not enough, please help to let me know how I can get more message when the error happens. I am a newbee to JAVA and activemq. Hope I can learn more from you. Thank you so much.

Comment: You've provided no context for anyone to even guess at what might be going wrong.  Provide more details in the question like what clients are being used and what they are doing at the time of exception etc.

Comment: Thank you, Tim. How about now? does the message is enough? If it does not, please let me know. :).

Answer (score 0):

It is like that even the activemq reports the error, but the broker works well.